# Passing ENV variables does not work with docker-compose

Tags: docker, variables, parameters, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am struggling with passing ENV variables using docker-compose

I have a `Dockerfile` to build the container with a Java app:

```
FROM alpine:latest

ENV ftp_ip 127.0.0.1
ENV mongo_ip 127.0.0.1
ENV quorum_ip http://localhost:22000

RUN apk add --update openjdk8 && mkdir /var/backend/
RUN apk update
COPY license-system-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /var/backend/
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT [ "java", "-jar", "-Dspring.quorum.host=${quorum_ip}", "-Dspring.ftp.server=${ftp_ip}", "-Dspring.data.mongodb.host=${mongo_ip}","/var/backend/license-system-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" ]
```

Then, the docker compose file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  backend:
    network_mode: host
    build: backend
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - mongo_ip=${mongo_ip}
      - ftp_ip=${ftp_ip}
      - quorum_ip=${quorum_ip}
```

Finally, the container is started by a bash command:

```
quorum_ip="$1" mongo_ip="$2" ftp_ip="$3" docker-compose up -d --build
```

but `docker inspect` shows nothing promising. The variables are not set properly (they are using the default values from dockerfile) and the params arent changed even to the default values...

```
        "Env": [
            "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
            "ftp_ip=127.0.0.1",
            "mongo_ip=127.0.0.1",
            "quorum_ip=http://localhost:22000"
        ],
        "Cmd": null,
        "ArgsEscaped": true,
        "Image": "sha256:3ce51f52d70127f22462eafdb60321a4e477a4bec5aa092e860b8485e8575c26",
        "Volumes": null,
        "WorkingDir": "",
        "Entrypoint": [
            "java",
            "-jar",
            "-Dspring.quorum.host=${quorum_ip}",
            "-Dspring.ftp.server=${ftp_ip}",
            "-Dspring.data.mongodb.host=${mongo_ip}",
            "/var/backend/license-system-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"
        ]
```

Am I missing something? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You `docker inspect imagename` or `docker inspect container`? It seems you use the former.

Comment: @dziki If you need to use ENV variables use the entrypoint like this: `ENTRYPOINT java -jar -Dspring.quorum.host=${quorum_ip} -Dspring.ftp.server=${ftp_ip} -Dspring.data.mongodb.host=${mongo_ip} /var/backend/license-system-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Comment: @Mihai Your comment solved my problem!

Comment: @dziki I added it as an answer. good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use environmnet varibles in your entrypoint, you should use the "shell form" instead of the "exec form".

```
ENTRYPOINT java -jar -Dspring.quorum.host=${quorum_ip} -Dspring.ftp.server=${ftp_ip} -Dspring.data.mongodb.host=${mongo_ip} /var/backend/license-system-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

You could probably make it work with the "exec form" but it only complicates the syntax.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use build args instead of envs to build an image from Dockerfile

Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:latest

ARG ftp_ip
ARG mongo_ip
ARG quorum_ip

RUN apk add --update openjdk8 && mkdir /var/backend/
RUN apk update
COPY license-system-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /var/backend/
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT [ "java", "-jar", "-Dspring.quorum.host="${quorum_ip}, "-Dspring.ftp.server="${ftp_ip}, "-Dspring.data.mongodb.host="${mongo_ip},"/var/backend/license-system-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" ]
```

docker-compose

```
version: "3"
services:
  backend:
    network_mode: host
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./path/to/backend/Dockerfile
      args:
        - mongo_ip=${mongo_ip}
        - ftp_ip=${ftp_ip}
        - quorum_ip=${quorum_ip}
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

.env (To pass envs for use in docker-compose. docker-compose automatically fetches envs from .env file if it exists)

```
ftp_ip=127.0.0.1
mongo_ip=127.0.0.1
quorum_ip=http://localhost:22000
```

And then run docker-compose build to build image with correct envs

Comment: there is something wrong with Your answer, I get: ERROR: unexpected error reading Dockerfile: read /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder628289201/backend: is a directory

Comment: Ok, i have solved this, but now I get: ERROR: Service 'backend' failed to build: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder093448755/license-system-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar: no such file or directory

Comment: in `dockerfile` you have to specify the path of your backend Dockerfile

Comment: just copy the jar file to your project directory and give the path relative to the project directory in the `COPY` command. Because when using build `context` option, docker searches for files relative to the context(Which in your case is the same as project directory)

Comment: Everything seems to be fine, the container builds, but it doesnt seem to pass the variables from .env file :( and I get errors like this: 2019-06-03 08:56:23.239  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Adding discovered server ${mongo_ip}:27017 to client view of cluster
2019-06-03 08:56:23.285  INFO 1 --- [mongo_ip}:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server ${mongo_ip}:27017

Comment: Figured it out. Change your ENTRYPOINT to `ENTRYPOINT [ "java", "-jar", "-Dspring.quorum.host="${quorum_ip}, "-Dspring.ftp.server="${ftp_ip}, "-Dspring.data.mongodb.host="${mongo_ip},"/var/backend/license-system-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" ]` See updated answer

Comment: It is not working :( docker logs backend_backend_1                                                                                                        ~/D/backend-scripts
sh: -jar,: unknown operand

Comment: Don't know much about java console but can you verify entrypoint using docker inspect?

Comment: "Entrypoint": [
                "/bin/sh",
                "-c",
                "[ \"java\", \"-jar\", \"-Dspring.quorum.host=\"${quorum_ip}, \"-Dspring.ftp.server=\"${ftp_ip}, \"-Dspring.data.mongodb.host=\"${mongo_ip}, \"/var/backend/license-system-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\" ]"]